# Jquery : Light box closing automatically :( 

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

light box closing automatically with in seconds. Could you help me please

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lightbox').click(function(){
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
        close_box();
    });

    $('.backdrop').click(function(){
        close_box();
    });

});

function close_box()
{
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });
}
```

CSS

```
    .backdrop
    {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#000;
        opacity: .0;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        z-index:50;
        display:none;
    }


    .box
    {
        position:absolute;
        top:20%;
        left:30%;
        width:500px;
        height:300px;
        background:#ffffff;
        z-index:51;
        padding:10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
        display:none;
    }

    .close
    {
        float:right;
        margin-right:6px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

HTML

```
 <a href="" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>

 <div class="backdrop">
    <div class="box"><div class="close">x</div>This is the lightbox!!!</div>
 </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/yx6W3/)**

Comment: What is the visual effect you are trying to achieve? What element is .lightbox? Could you provide a fiddle that replicates the problem?

Comment: @Rudolph Gottesheim http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/yx6W3/ fiddle also not working. It is working in Firefox

Comment: it's working as expected in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yx6W3/1/)

Comment: @denolk it is closing wherever click and also half of the page doesn't cover whole page :(

Comment: I've tweaked your fiddle to get it to work. I've had to change several things, but the key to your "closes wherever I click" is probably e.stopPropagation() http://jsfiddle.net/yx6W3/2/ .. let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tyr with this code  http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/yx6W3/

Answer (score 1):

This happens as the form is reloading(Postback happens)... prevent it by adding 'return false' to your code...so your code will be like..

```
  $('.lightbox').click(function(){
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
             return false;
        });
```